# javascript : correct use of insertBefore()

Tags: javascript

I have created javascript program in that I have created div tag in body and prompt in order to accept text from user after that I have created div and want to add prompt text to div.The new div should be display before already created one and for that I have used insertBefore(). I tried to get the value in console and I am getting values in console. but my program is not working as per expectation.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>trail</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">

    .pink{
        background-color: pink;     
    }

    .green{
        background-color: #71e887;
    }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var movieText =  prompt("What movie do you like?"); 

    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    parent = newDiv.parentNode;
    newDiv.className = "green";

    var text = document.createTextNode(movieText + " is a good movie");

    newDiv.innerHTML  = text;
    newDiv.appendChild(text);   

    var beforeMe = document.getElementById("div1");     
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, beforeMe);

    </script>

</head>
<body>


<br>

<div class="pink" id = "div1"> 
    I love watching movies <br/>
    This is one of my favorite movie:
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

my output:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

expected output:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: remove `newDiv.innerHTML  = text;`

Comment: @JaromandaX but it's requirement to add text in div by using innerHTML.

Comment: ok, don't do it then ... I mean `newDiv.appendChild(text);` is doing that already, but what would I know

Comment: @JaromandaX I removed 'newDiv.appendChild(text);' but still I am getting error at insertBefore().

Comment: Why did you remove the one I told you to keep? Obviously you know better

Comment: @JaromandaX I am not getting what are you trying to say. I keep or remove I am getting same error at insertBefore(). Could you please be more specific. Thanks

Comment: see the first comment. I said "remove `newDiv.innerHTML = text;` " and that's all I said - pretty **specific**, but you decided to remove the other one

Comment: @JaromandaX that's what I said in second comment. it's requirement in program to use "newDiv.innerHTML  = text;"

Comment: Odd "requirement" ... so, you need to add TEXT to innerHTML, not a TextNode object ... see answer

Comment: I just realised your other mistake. `document.body` is null because your code is running immediately in the `head` element before `body` is even seen by the browser

Comment: @JaromandaX so should I put my code in function ? and call function from body ?

Comment: yes, but don't make a text node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **@pari** mention, you are inserting a text node objet using innerHTML. This function will performance a `.toString()` to the text node. That is way you are receiving the output `[object text]`. If you are required to use `innerHTML` then just go with `.innerHTML(movieText + " is a good movie")`
Or you can use the text node like this :

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode(movieText + " is a good movie");
newDiv.appendChild(textNode);
```

but do not use both at the same time.

Comment: how to put br tag after created div ?